# How to set travel mode to "Flight" in google map direction API .

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm using google map direction API in our application. Map with directions working well with traveling modes like Driving,Walking,Transit and Bicycling. But it **not showing flight directions** when we enter **two cities from different countries.** So for showing flight directions what should i do? Please help.

Answer (score 10):

There is no FLIGHT [TravelMode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#TravelMode) in the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

**google.maps.TravelMode constants**

> The valid travel modes that can be specified in a DirectionsRequest as well as the travel modes returned in a DirectionsStep.
>
> - **BICYCLING**   Specifies a bicycling directions request.
> - **DRIVING** Specifies a driving directions request.
> - **TRANSIT** Specifies a transit directions request.
> - **WALKING** Specifies a walking directions request.

One option would be to draw a normal or geodesic [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polyline) between the two airports.