# Issue in creating route by Google directions api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

Here is the URL i am using :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.6139,77.2090&destination=25.992003,-80.117802&key=API KEY
```

When i am hitting this URL in browser , i am getting following response :

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Source location is delhi and destination location is 3555 N Ocean Dr, Hollywood, FL 33019, USA   . If i change the destination location to any other then i am getting values for geocoded waypoints but why not for above values?

Help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is caused by travel modes restriction in Direction API.

## Travel Modes

> When you calculate directions, you may specify the transportation `mode` to use. By default, directions are calculated as `driving` directions. The following travel modes are supported:
>
> - `driving` (default) indicates standard driving directions using the road network.
> - `walking` requests walking directions via pedestrian paths & sidewalks (where available).
> - `bicycling` requests bicycling directions via bicycle paths & preferred streets (where available).
> - `transit` requests directions via public transit routes (where available). If you set the mode to `transit`, you can optionally specify either a `departure_time` or an `arrival_time`. If neither time is specified, the `departure_time` defaults to now (that is, the departure time defaults to the current time). You can also optionally include a `transit_mode` and/or a `transit_routing_preference`.

Sample Route in Google Maps App(Browser)

```
https://www.google.com.ph/maps/dir/28.6139,77.209/'25.992003,-80.117802'/@22.2476068,-39.0397189,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m0!1m3!2m2!1d-80.117802!2d25.992003
```

If you will check that link in your browser, the travel mode is flight which is not available in the Direction API.

Here is a previous question : [How to set travel mode to “Flight” in google map direction API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502261/how-to-set-travel-mode-to-flight-in-google-map-direction-api)

Hope this helps.